# In search for a word in German

Tags: single-word-requests, german

I asked this question before, but I am looking for it in a different language.

The language of the word is German. 
The meaning of the word I am looking is 'shadowless' or 'Has no shadow.'

Comment: The German Language site would be a more appropriate place to ask this question: http://german.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal translation of *Shadowless* and also perfectly valid in German would be the word:

> Schattenlos

A literal and also perfectly valid translation of *Without a shadow* would be:

> Ohne (einen) Schatten

Yep, German can be easy sometimes

Comment: @BlazeOfLight you're welcome. I'd though go look at the german.stackexchange.com page for future German word requests ;)

Comment: Alright, I will next time.